# Grouped stacked bar chart in ggplot2 where each stack corresponds to its y axis value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering if my request is possible in ggplot2.

I am looking to enhance a bar plot where I group two bars by hour (1:24) corresponding to model1 and model2's error measured in MAPE (mean absolute percentage error), where hours are the x axis and MAPE is plotted on the y axis.

The chart I explained is simple and informative, but the enhancement I am looking to do is fill each bar with MAPE by Date. Date is the fourth column in my data frame. I would like the fill to correspond to the MAPE value model1 or model2 produced on a given date.

All I have been able to plot so far is each date that makes up the total MAPE calculation in a given model's bar. It is informative in the sense that it shows which dates were used in the error calculation, but it does not tell the viewer which dates were responsible for the least/greatest model error.

I pasted my data at the bottom of the post to avoid clutter. Here are my results so far:

My first attempt with facet_grid resulted in this:

```
ggplot(Hourly_compare, aes(x = Hour, y = MAPE, fill = as.factor(Date)))+
  geom_bar(position= "stack", stat = "identity") + facet_grid(~ Model)
```

[image]

As you can see, each date's fill is the same length in each bar. I would like the date's fill to correspond to the MAPE value for that given date.

My second attempt produced this gnarly chart:

```
ggplot(Hourly_compare, aes(x = Hour, y = MAPE, fill = as.factor(Date), color = Model))+
  geom_bar(position= "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Model1"="red", "Model2"="black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24))
```

[image]

This is more ideal for me as I would like to keep each model's results grouped together by hour as separate bars, but I would like the bars to be stacked with each date's model errors corresponding to their MAPE value.

Here is my data:

```
Hourly_compare <- dput(Hourly_compare)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
18412, 18412, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419), class = "Date"), Hour = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 
19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 
13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 
21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 
15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 
23, 23, 24, 24), Model = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", 
"Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", 
"Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2", "Model1", "Model2"
), MAPE = c(0.45, 1.33, 0.41, 1.17, 0.4, 1.23, 0.45, 1.32, 0.45, 
1.48, 0.62, 1.82, 0.7, 1.69, 0.69, 1.16, 1.37, 1.56, 1.56, 1.48, 
1.64, 1.42, 1.48, 1.45, 1.23, 1.42, 1.18, 1.66, 1.22, 1.8, 1.36, 
2.21, 1.61, 2.5, 1.99, 2.87, 1.93, 2.55, 2.01, 2.61, 1.82, 2.75, 
1.92, 2.53, 1.71, 2.31, 1.5, 2.04, 0.45, 1.33, 0.41, 1.17, 0.4, 
1.23, 0.45, 1.32, 0.45, 1.48, 0.62, 1.82, 0.7, 1.69, 0.69, 1.16, 
1.37, 1.56, 1.56, 1.48, 1.64, 1.42, 1.48, 1.45, 1.23, 1.42, 1.18, 
1.66, 1.22, 1.8, 1.36, 2.21, 1.61, 2.5, 1.99, 2.87, 1.93, 2.55, 
2.01, 2.61, 1.82, 2.75, 1.92, 2.53, 1.71, 2.31, 1.5, 2.04, 0.45, 
1.33, 0.41, 1.17, 0.4, 1.23, 0.45, 1.32, 0.45, 1.48, 0.62, 1.82, 
0.7, 1.69, 0.69, 1.16, 1.37, 1.56, 1.56, 1.48, 1.64, 1.42, 1.48, 
1.45, 1.23, 1.42, 1.18, 1.66, 1.22, 1.8, 1.36, 2.21, 1.61, 2.5, 
1.99, 2.87, 1.93, 2.55, 2.01, 2.61, 1.82, 2.75, 1.92, 2.53, 1.71, 
2.31, 1.5, 2.04)), row.names = c(NA, -144L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
    18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
    18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 18405, 
    18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
    18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 
    18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18412, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
    18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
    18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 18419, 
    18419, 18419, 18419), class = "Date"), Hour = c(1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 
        11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26, 
        27:28, 29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:42, 
        43:44, 45:46, 47:48, 49:50, 51:52, 53:54, 55:56, 57:58, 
        59:60, 61:62, 63:64, 65:66, 67:68, 69:70, 71:72, 73:74, 
        75:76, 77:78, 79:80, 81:82, 83:84, 85:86, 87:88, 89:90, 
        91:92, 93:94, 95:96, 97:98, 99:100, 101:102, 103:104, 
        105:106, 107:108, 109:110, 111:112, 113:114, 115:116, 
        117:118, 119:120, 121:122, 123:124, 125:126, 127:128, 
        129:130, 131:132, 133:134, 135:136, 137:138, 139:140, 
        141:142, 143:144)), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your plot; it just shows what's in your data. The MAPE for each hour *is* the same on each date. Look:

```
Hourly_compare %>% filter(Model == "Model1") %>% arrange(Hour)
# A tibble: 72 x 4
# Groups:   Date, Hour [72]
   Date        Hour Model   MAPE
   <date>     <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2020-05-23     1 Model1  0.45
 2 2020-05-30     1 Model1  0.45
 3 2020-06-06     1 Model1  0.45
 4 2020-05-23     2 Model1  0.41
 5 2020-05-30     2 Model1  0.41
 6 2020-06-06     2 Model1  0.41
 7 2020-05-23     3 Model1  0.4 
 8 2020-05-30     3 Model1  0.4 
 9 2020-06-06     3 Model1  0.4 
10 2020-05-23     4 Model1  0.45
```

You can see that MAPE is 0.45 for each of the three dates on hour 1, 0.41 on each of the three dates in hour two, and so on. This pattern repeats throughout:

```r
Hourly_compare %>% filter(Model == "Model2") %>% arrange(-Hour)
# A tibble: 72 x 4
# Groups:   Date, Hour [72]
   Date        Hour Model   MAPE
   <date>     <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2020-05-23    24 Model2  2.04
 2 2020-05-30    24 Model2  2.04
 3 2020-06-06    24 Model2  2.04
 4 2020-05-23    23 Model2  2.31
 5 2020-05-30    23 Model2  2.31
 6 2020-06-06    23 Model2  2.31
 7 2020-05-23    22 Model2  2.53
 8 2020-05-30    22 Model2  2.53
 9 2020-06-06    22 Model2  2.53
10 2020-05-23    21 Model2  2.75
# ... with 62 more rows
```

So you should expect the three colours within each bar to have the same size.

Comment: Or `Hourly_compare %>% group_by(Model, Date) %>% summarise(S = sum(MAPE))`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. That is embarrassing, I need to re-calculate and re-attempt. I should be able to edit my post once I do. Sorry for not catching that.

Comment: Not embarrassing at all @user3720887. Sometimes you need a fresh pair of eyes on a problem to find what it is you've overlooked. A well-asked question on SO is a good way to get some fresh eyes on it, and that's what you've done. I'm guessing that your existing code will work great with your fixed-up data.

Comment: Yep, it sure does. The facet_grid option looks the cleanest now that I've fixed things. Thank you, Allan. Mind if I delete the post?

Comment: Sure @user3720887. No worries

Comment: @Rui Barradas Your suggestion also works quite well. I can include my original grouped bar plot by model and hour and then create a chart with your suggestion next to it. That might be easier on the eyes.